# Чтение из strings.xml

Tags: android

Как во время исполнения получить данные из strings.xml по имени строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ в этом уроке - [Урок 11. Папка res/values. Используем ресурсы приложения.](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/18-urok-11-papka-resvalues-ispolzuem-resursy-prilozhenija.html).

Если быть прицельнее, то ответ в такой строке

```
 getResources().getString(R.string.tvBottomText);
```

Comment: KoVadim, спасибо, то, что нужно

Comment: а так еще короче getString(R.string.tvBottomText); =)

Comment: не стоит так делать, кода не намного меньше, но из за за этого бывают крайне не приятные ошибки

Comment: @KoVadim подскажите, как быть если обращаешься из класса? ( не из активити). Как обратиться к ресурсам?

Comment: Надо в конструктор класса передавать Context, допустим  
    
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(MainActivity.this);
А в вашем классе SomeClass  
    
    public SomeClass {
    
        Context context;
    
        SomeClass(Context context) {
             this.context = context;
        }
    
        protected void someMethod() {
            ... ваш код
            String str = context.getResources().getString(R.string.tvBottomText);
        }
    }
Т.е. не просто getResources().getString(R.string.tvBottomText) а context.getResources().getString(R.string.tvBottomText)

Comment: @Garf1eld, так же можно вместо  
    
    MainActivity.this
использовать  
    
    getApplicationContext()